# How to represent `where` helper with ::?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code (insignificant):

```
where(is.double)
```

In which package is the `where` helper inserted?

I don't want to load `dplyr`. I want something like this:

```
dplyr::where(is.double)
```

How to do this?

Comment: It is in `tidyselect`

Comment: In case anyone wants to know how to find it: `tidyselect::vars_select_helpers:::where()`. Thanks @akrun.

Comment: @neves That isn’t valid R syntax. ;-) I think you meant `tidyselect::vars_select_helpers$where()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right. In the Rstudio script, `tidyselect::vars_select_helpers:::where()` appears, but when run it doesn't work. Thanks for the correction.